# WiX INSTALLDIR not set after editing it per hand (not per BrowseDialog)

Tags: wix

i try to let the user set the INSTALLDIR per hand, but the value from the textfield is not transfered into the INSTALLDIR Variable.
When the user click on the browsebutton and select the target directory it works.

```
<Product>
...
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
...
</Product>
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="HereIAm">
        ....
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<UI>
    ...
    <Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
    ....
</UI>
<UI>
    <Dialog Id="CustInstallDirDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
        ...
        <Control Id="FolderLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgFolderLabel)" />
        <Control Id="Folder" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="100" Width="320" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Indirect="yes" />
        <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="120" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgChange)" />
    </Dialog>
</UI>
```

But i have another field, where i can edit my text per hand.

```
<product>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_XMLDATASTORE" Value="DATASTOREDIR" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetDataStorePath"
        Property="WIXUI_XMLDATASTORE"
        Value="[DATASTOREDIR]"
        Execute="immediate"
        />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SetDataStorePath"
            Before="InstallInitialize"
        />              
</product>

<UI Id="ServiceAccount">
    <Dialog Id="ServiceAccountDlg" ...>
        ...
        <Control Id="DataStoreLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="150" Width="290" Height="15" NoPrefix="yes" 
            Text="Please enter Datastore Location" />
        <Control Id="CDataStore" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="165" Width="220" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_XMLDATASTORE" Indirect="yes"/>
        <Control Id="ChangeFolderDS" Type="PushButton" X="250" Y="165" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgChange)" />
    </Dialog>
</UI>
<UI>
    <Publish Dialog="ServiceAccountDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="ServiceAccountDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ISISIPSettingsDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="ServiceAccountDlg" Control="ChangeFolderDS" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_XMLDATASTORE]" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="ServiceAccountDlg" Control="ChangeFolderDS" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the error.
The following line was missing in the CustInstallDirDlg:

```
<Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
```

now it looks like this:

```
<Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="CustInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```